# Join string with INT django Python

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have my `views.py`

```
class ShopCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('shop_id',)
    model = models.Shop

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)

        dept_obj = models.departemen.objects.get(seller_id=self.object.id)
        dept_name = dept_obj.name

        date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        year = date.year
        month = date.month

        seller_count = seller_obj.count()

        if seller_count > 999:
            counted = seller_count - 999

        self.object.shop_id = dept_name + join_date + year + month + counted
        self.object.save()


        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

here my explain

`dept_name` return string

eg.

PT. **C**ounter **A**venger **M**anequin = CAM

**P**T. **I**nternational **J**ob = PIJ

I want my code take first char of letter. but don't have idea how to right now. find the solution but its only for show on `template.html`

so `self.object.shop_id = dept_name + year + month + counted` will like:

`CAM71804001`

its mix string & int. also last `3` har if return `1`. i need make it `001`

thank you!

Comment: Why `PT. Counter Avenger Manequin` -> `CAM` and not `PCAM` but `PT. International Job` -> PIJ ? Your question isn't very clear to me.

Comment: just take `3` char. so if `PT. Counter` will be `PTC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the `dept_name` with `.split(" ")` and then use only the first letter of each word with `[:1]`.

Example:

```
dept_name = "Counter Avenger Manequin"
shop_id = ""

for word in dept_name.split(" "):
   shop_id += word[:1]

shop_id += join_date + year[2:] + month + counted
print shop_id
```

This will output:

```
CAM71804001
```

---

**Edit**: Same for the year, to get `18` from `2018` use:

```
year = "2018"
print year[2:]
```

This will output:

```
18
```

Comment: year value `2018` how if i want `18`

Comment: @BudiGunawan If year="2018" then just use year[2:] to get the last 2 digits of the year, same way as getting the first letter of the object. (Updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead. To pick the first letter of a string just index it with `[0]`. You can pass `{:03}` to zero pad with three zeroes, like so

```
self.object.shop_id = "{}{}{}{}{:03}".format(dept_name[0], join_date, year , month, counted)
```

Comment: `dept_name[0]` return all first character?.. how if i want 3 ?